# SQL natural join query not selecting expected results

Tags: sql, natural-join

I'm trying to make a query with two natural joins, but I'm not getting the expected results. I want to retrieve the employers data who have an assigned project. In addition I want to retrieve the project code, the project name and the hours that the employee has spent on the project.

This is the SQL query I'm trying to make:

```
SELECT empno, ename, sal, prono, hours, pname
FROM emp NATURAL RIGHT JOIN emppro NATURAL JOIN pro;
```

This is the emp table:

```
EMPNO ENAME  JOB         MGR HIREDATE     SAL     COMM    DEPTNO
----- ---------- --------- ----- -------- ------- ------- ------
7369 SMITH   CLERK      7902 17/12/80     800             20
7499 ALLEN   SALESMAN   7698 20/02/81   1,600     300     30
7521 WARD    SALESMAN   7698 22/02/81   1,250     500     30
7566 JONES   MANAGER    7839 02/04/81   2,975             20
7654 MARTIN  SALESMAN   7698 28/09/81   1,250     1,400   30
7698 BLAKE   MANAGER    7839 01/05/81   2,850             30
7782 CLARK   MANAGER    7839 09/06/81   2,450             10
7788 SCOTT   ANALYST    7566 19/04/87   3,000             20
7839 KING    PRESIDENT   17/11/81       5,000             10
7844 TURNER  SALESMAN   7698 08/09/81   1,500      0      30
7876 ADAMS   CLERK      7788 23/05/87   1,100             20
7900 JAMES   CLERK      7698 03/12/81     950             30
7902 FORD    ANALYST    7566 03/12/81   3,000             20
7934 MILLER  CLERK      7782 23/01/82   1,300             10
```

This is the emppro table:

```
EMPNO      PRONO      HOURS
----- ---------- ----------
7499        1004     15
7499        1005     12
7521        1004     10
7521        1008      8
7654        1001     16
7654        1006     15
7654        1008      5
7844        1005      6
7934        1001      4
```

And this is the pro table:

```
PRONO       PNAME      LOC          DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ------------- ------
1001        P1         BOSTON         20
1004        P4         CHICAGO        30
1005        P5         CHICAGO        30
1006        P6         LOS ANGELES    30
1008        P8         NEW YORK       30
```

If I make the query with inner joins it works properly, why? I think I'm not understanding correctly the natural join...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one uses `NATURAL JOIN` precisely for these reasons. Your query:

```
SELECT empno, ename, sal, prono, hours, pname
FROM emp NATURAL RIGHT JOIN emppro NATURAL JOIN pro;
```

Is equivalent to this query:

```
SELECT empno, ename, sal, prono, hours, pname
FROM emp 
RIGHT JOIN emppro ON emp.empno = emppro.empno
JOIN pro ON emppro.prono = pro.prono
  AND emp.deptno = pro.deptno -- This predicate is completely unexpected and wrong
```

As you can see above, you accidentally joined over the `DEPTNO` columns that happen to be present in both `emp` and `pro`, but you didn't want to join over that column.

Think about your original query this way:

```
SELECT empno, ename, sal, prono, hours, pname
FROM A NATURAL JOIN pro;
```

Where `A = (emp NATURAL RIGHT JOIN emppro)`. So, when joining `pro` to `A`, there are two columns that `A` and `pro` have in common.

Comment: Wow thanks! Cleary answer, I didn't realize that mistake. So when I use natural join it matches all the columns with the same name, right? I thought that it only matches with the previous table.

Comment: Yes: All the columns with the same name. I'll update the answer and explain why.

Comment: Okay, I understand it clearly now. Very clearly explanation as before, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`NATURAL JOIN` is just an error waiting to happen (as is presumably happening in your case).  It chooses the columns for joining based on the *names* in the associated tables/subqueries.  It doesn't even use declared foreign key relationships.  Seems like a real bad idea to me.  Just forget that it exists.

So, use `USING` instead (or if you prefer `ON`).  Something like this:

```
SELECT empno, ename, sal, prono, hours, pname
FROM emp RIGHT JOIN emppro
     emppro
     USING (EMPNO) INNER JOIN
     pro
     USING (PRONO);
```

I'm not a fan of `RIGHT JOIN` either.  I think `LEFT JOIN` is easier to follow logically, particularly if you are learning SQL ("keep all the rows in the first table and matching rows in the second").

Comment: Thanks, very great tip to apply!